# oracle apex GTT preserve rows after logout

Tags: session, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, global-temp-tables

I have a GTT in my oracle apex application.

```
  CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE "SEARCH" 
   (    "CODE" VARCHAR2(15 BYTE), 
    "HEAD" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "BRCODE" VARCHAR2(3 BYTE)
   ) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS ;
```

But the GTT preserves it's rows even after the user log out from the application. If another user login to the application, he can access the same data created by the previous user. What might be the problem with GTT or session ?

Comment: See here - https://community.oracle.com/thread/2331603

Comment: Thank you @RLOG .

Comment: @RLOG  then if I'm using GTT with "on commit delete rows", can another user access the data before executing  commit statement ?

Comment: I don't think so, but you should test it. If you are using the data from the tables in your APEX application rather than as part of a background plsql task then it would likely be better to use APEX Collections.

Comment: ya I too felt apex collection better than GTT  in this case . anyway thanks a lot RLOG

Answer (score 0):

Please read this answer thread from oracle community.  [GTT - Global Temporary Table - Problem with Apex](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2331603)